# What are asp.net vNext features?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

What is `asp.net vNext`? what are the new features included in `vNext`?Is it similar to `asp.net-mvc-6`? When will it be released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is asp.net vNext?

---

> ASP.NET vNext, which is an updated version of ASP.NET that been
>   optimized for cloud Web development.

You can reference [The next generation of net asp.net vnext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/05/12/the-next-generation-of-net-asp-net-vnext.aspx)

---

> ASP.NET vNext will let you deploy your own version of the .NET Framework on an app-by-app-basis. One app with new libraries can’t break an app next door with a different version.

Refrence: [IntroducingASPNETVNext](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETVNext.aspx)